# Using PrintDocument in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i Using below code in WPF?

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Name", new Font("tahoma", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Last", new Font("tahoma", 10), Brushes.Black, 100, 120);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet due to points however what you show is a method added to a eventhandler, here is an example i have made for printing text into a document:

adding method to the eventhandler:

```
 printDocument.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument_PrintPage);
```

The eventhandler method (your case what you have posted):

```
 void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int charactersOnPage = 0;
        int linesPerPage = 0;

        // Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters  
        // of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
        e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, printFont,
            e.MarginBounds.Size, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic,
            out charactersOnPage, out linesPerPage);

        // Draws the string within the bounds of the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,
            e.MarginBounds, System.Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        // Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
        stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage);

        // Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
        e.HasMorePages = (stringToPrint.Length > 0);
    }
```

Fire off the print:

```
 printDocument.Print();
```

Comment: my code using in WINDOWSFORMAPPLICATION, so can i have using your code in WPF?

Comment: i think WPF dosnt support 'Graphics.DrawString'

Comment: I only answered on how to use the method you posted, and those are part of system.drawing, and specifically for printing. I assumed you wanted to print from your wpf application

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen He wants to know how to in WPF not in Windows Forms.

Comment: @SHINJaeGuk this should work on both, its dealing with printing, and its actually not really related to UI, its all just .net, so it should work on both.